# Reading XML file in vba userform using XMLDOM

Tags: vba, xmldom

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<catalog>


-<book id="bk101">

<author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>

<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>

<genre>Computer</genre>

<price>44.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>

<description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk102">

<author>Ralls, Kim</author>

<title>Midnight Rain</title>

<genre>Fantasy</genre>

<price>5.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>

<description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk103">

<author>Corets, Eva</author>

<title>Maeve Ascendant</title>

<genre>Fantasy</genre>

<price>5.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>

<description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk104">

<author>Corets, Eva</author>

<title>Oberon's Legacy</title>

<genre>Fantasy</genre>

<price>5.95</price>

<publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>

<description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve Ascendant.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk105">

<author>Corets, Eva</author>

<title>The Sundered Grail</title>

<genre>Fantasy</genre>

<price>5.95</price>

<publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>

<description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, battle one another for control of England. Sequel to Oberon's Legacy.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk106">

<author>Randall, Cynthia</author>

<title>Lover Birds</title>

<genre>Romance</genre>

<price>4.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>

<description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk107">

<author>Thurman, Paula</author>

<title>Splish Splash</title>

<genre>Romance</genre>

<price>4.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>

<description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk108">

<author>Knorr, Stefan</author>

<title>Creepy Crawlies</title>

<genre>Horror</genre>

<price>4.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>

<description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions and other insects.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk109">

<author>Kress, Peter</author>

<title>Paradox Lost</title>

<genre>Science Fiction</genre>

<price>6.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>

<description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems of being quantum.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk110">

<author>O'Brien, Tim</author>

<title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>

<genre>Computer</genre>

<price>36.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>

<description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk111">

<author>O'Brien, Tim</author>

<title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>

<genre>Computer</genre>

<price>36.95</price>

<publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>

<description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more.</description>

</book>


-<book id="bk112">

<author>Galos, Mike</author>

<title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>

<genre>Computer</genre>

<price>49.95</price>

<publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>

<description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth, looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are integrated into a comprehensive development environment.</description>

</book>

</catalog>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read the guidelines about asking questions on StackOverflow. Your XML is not formatted correctly, nor is it valid (hyphens). You don't provide a problem description or any code you've developed to solve your problem. Click the "Edit" button below your question in order to make it more meaningful. No one can help you based on this. Put in some effort and people here will take the time out of their busy days to help...

Answer (score 1):

Cre­ate the object of “Microsoft XML Parser” (Microsoft.XMLDOM is the COM object of Microsoft XML Parser)

```
Set oXML­File = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

Load the XML from a spec­i­fied path.

```
XML­File­Name = "C:\Sample.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
```

Select the tag from the XML file using SelectN­odes or SelectS­in­gleN­ode.

`SelectN­odes` - Selects a list of nodes matches the Xpath pattern.

```
Set TitleN­odes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/title/text()")
```

`SelectS­in­gleN­ode` – Selects the first XMLN­ode that matches the pattern.

```
Set Nodes_Particular = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/book[4]/title/text()")
```

Iter­ate through all the Node by using Nodes.length and Node­Value.

```
For i = 0 To (TitleNodes.Length — 1)
Title = TitleNodes(i).NodeValue
```

Read the attrib­utes by using `Attribute.Length` and `getAt­tribute`.

```
Set Nodes_Attribute = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")
For i = 0 To (Nodes_Attribute.Length — 1)
Attrib­utes = Nodes_Attribute(i).getAttribute("id")
```

Read the par­tic­u­lar index value from the XML File

```
oXML­File.SelectS­in­gleN­ode("/catalog/book[4]/title/text()")
```

Get all the val­ues of par­tic­u­lar type of nodes.

```
oXML­File.SelectN­odes("/catalog/book/title[../genre = 'Fan­tasy']/text()")
```